# Facebook Php sdk to handle at server side?

Tags: php, facebook-php-sdk

I have been trying to use facebook php-sdk for my webapplication but I am not able to get my requirement fulfilled from the code available with php sdk. My firewall is placed on clients such that they cannot open facebook urls on their system, only the application server can open the facebook url. Thus, I need a means that enables the client to login and share on facebook without ever changing the context root to facebook on client machines and do all the interactions with facebook via application server. I am reiterating my requirement, which is that the context root or url on client machines should never start from facebook, it can be a part of the query string from my context root (ie. for example say site url is www.some-sitename.com, I want facebook to appears as "www.some-sitename.com/.../facebook.com").

I would be highly obliged for any help regarding the same.

Answer (score 0):

This won't work unfortunately as Facebook uses OAuth for authentication so there is a dependancy there that the client has to go to Facebook briefly to complete the authentication and supply your server with the "code" necessary to generate an access token.

Comment: is there any  way we can handle the request from our application server?

Comment: No, you will always need the user to login to Facebook.com and get a session so that you can get a user specific token for your app. If you had their user/pass you could technically do this by simulating their actions of logging in and giving your application access serverside but this would be difficult and a big security risk for your users. Facebook is working on an authentication method for users without access to a browser but they'll still need another device with access (say their phones): https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/devices/

Answer (score 0):

You will need to make your web application as a proxy server which will can serve any from facebook.php [proxy script like glype](http://www.glype.com/) can work. But not I am not sure that it will work with facebook because of the way facebook authentication works.